# Enhanced for loop and null check of objects

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

lets say i have the following code:

```
for (AnyObject anyObject : anyObjectList) {
    System.out.println(anyObject.doSomething());
}
```

My question is: I read that its possible to add null to at least some kind of list types.
If im right: shouldn't be there always a null check before you access the method of the iterated class?
Im just asking because i have never seen so far a enhanced for loop with a null check like this for example:

```
for (AnyObject anyObject : anyObjectList) {
    if (anyObject != null) {
        System.out.println(anyObject.doSomething());
    }
}
```

Comment: If your program never adds null values, why should you check?

Comment: As always: it depends. If the possibility for null values is given, check for null (or prevent adding null values). If not, don't.

Comment: Sometimes you need `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you'd often want to know if there is a random `null` in your list when there shouldn't be. Your first snippet will throw an exception indicating the problem, but your second will consume the error silently.

You could also do something like this:

```
for (AnyObject anyObject : anyObjectList) {
    if (anyObject != null) {
        System.out.println(anyObject.doSomething());
    } else {
        /* something went wrong -- report error, debugging info, etc. */
    }
}
```

Comment: putting an `else {` would also help spot the null values

Comment: @vefthym That's true; I'll mention something about that.

Comment: I would prefer try catch and not if else ...as if and else will give a performance hit for larger list...

Comment: @StackFlowed First of all, you should never catch a `NullPointerException`. Second of all, performance is most certainly not a concern here (if anything `try`/`catch` would have worse performance).

Comment: Please check how I'm asking to do ! .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26760083/1085186

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want null in your list then most [`Queue`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Constraints.html) implementations (with the notable exception of [`LinkedList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)) don't accept `null`.

Or you can also 
use [`Constraints`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Constraints.html):

```
import com.google.common.collect.Constraints;
...
Constraints.constrainedList(new ArrayList(), Constraints.notNull())
```

from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) for maximum flexibility.

---

A better way of doing what you have would be

```
try {
    for (AnyObject anyObject : anyObjectList) {
        System.out.println(anyObject.doSomething());
    }
} catch (NullPointerException npe){
        // Do your logging here !
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for (AnyObject anyObject : anyObjectList) {
>     if (anyObject != null) {
>         System.out.println(anyObject.doSomething());
>     } else {
>         /* something went wrong -- report error, debugging info, etc. */
>     }
> }
> ```

This is a really bad way of null checking. Line 2 wont event execute when null occurs.

The answer by StackFlowed is better.

```
try {
    for (AnyObject anyObject : anyObjectList) {
        System.out.println(anyObject.doSomething());
    }
} catch (NullPointerException npe){
        // Do your logging here !
}
```

But we may have to skip the null and get other values. So I found a solution. The code must be like this:

```
for (AnyObject anyObject : checkIsEmpty(anyObjectList)) {
        System.out.println(anyObject.doSomething());
}

private <T> Iterable<T> checkIsEmpty(Iterable<T> iterable) {
        return iterable == null ? Collections.<T>emptyList() : iterable;
}
```